# Graph data from an Excel Pivot in a Tree Representation

Tags: excel, data-visualization, pivot-table, cart-analysis

I've been looking for a while to see if there's any add-on or software which allows data from an excel pivot to be graphed dynamically in a visual tree representation. I know of the likes of graphviz for manually visualising trees etc, but ideally, I should be able to change something in the pivot which would henceforth change the graph.

I'm trying to visualise journeys through a website by page and although I have this represented in pivot tables, I would love to be able to show this visually.

Comment: Maybe [NodeXL](http://nodexl.codeplex.com/)? (Not sure though if it can be updated dynamically like you want, I suspect not.) I've voted as off-topic, just asking about tools doesn't make it a statistical question.

Comment: This isn't really a stats question so much as it's a question about stats tools. I suggest you try asking over at StackOverflow.